# Create multiple files using COPY INTO in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is not an issue but looking for info on creating multiple files using COPY INTO on snowflake.

I am using the below query to create multiple files **(SINGLE=FALSE) and MAX_FILE_SIZE=4900000000,** trying to understand based on what criteria does snowflake decide how many files to create ?.

```
COPY INTO @stage/file.csv
FROM (select id, name, listagg(scores) from table where id='0001')
FILE_FORMAT = (type=csv compression='none' field_delimiter=';'
empty_field_as_null=false null_if=(''))
OVERWRITE=TRUE
MAX_FILE_SIZE=4900000000;
```

Here is the scenario:

1. I ran a file with 51000 records and snowflake created 4 files each around 0.3MB.
2. I ran a file with 10054763 records and snowflake created 16 files each around 32MB.

**Note:** The stage is connected to S3, so these files are uploaded to S3 from COPY INTO, that is the reason had to enable multiple file creation to avoid creating a file size more than the 5GB limit for S3.

Just trying to understand how are these split files created from the snowflake.

Any info from you all is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can't control the output size of file unloads, only the max file size. Snowflake probably wrote smaller files on run #1 to parallelize the operation. Here's some info on unloading: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Best-Practices-for-Data-Unloading

Comment: Agree with Greg.  The number and size of the files is based on maximum performance as it parallelizes the operation.  If you want to control the number/size of files, that would be a feature request.  Otherwise, just work out a process outside of Snowflake to combine the files afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, Greg and Suzy. Appreciate your response.